# How do I specify a primary key on table creation with haskellDB?

Tags: haskell, haskelldb

Currently I am using something like this:

```
dbCreateTable db "MyTable" [ ("Col1", (StringT, False)), ("Col2", (StringT, False)) ]
```

which works fine, but i'd like to make "Col1" the primary key. Do i need to go back to raw SQL?

edit:
This still seems to hold:
"The part of creating a database from Haskell itself is not very
useful, for example you cannot express foreign- and primary keys,
indexes and constraints. Even the most simple database will need
one of these."

From http://www.mijnadres.net/published/HaskellDB.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the edit notes, HaskellDB is not very good at creating tables at the moment. It's best to build a database first, and then extract the info.